# the lid of the jar

Tags: pronouns, possessives

Can one say

a. I took off the lid of the jar and emptied it.

b. I took off the jar's lid and emptied it.

c. I took off the jar lid and emptied it.

?

The intended meaning is that I emptied the jar after taking off its lid.

Many thanks.

Comment: Likely canonical question is [Is using the possessive s correct in "the car's antenna"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/is-using-the-possessive-s-correct-in-the-cars-antenna)

Comment: I took the jar's lid off, and emptied it.  **off** can also appear after "lid". Took...off.

Comment: The first-order parse of *it* in all these takes its referent to be the head of the prior NP, which is the *lid*. Obviously, most hearers will eventually  sort this out correctly, but on the principle that "Anything which can be misunderstood will be", I'd rephrase to preclude any possibility of being taken to mean that I emptied the lid: "I took off the lid and emptied the jar."

Comment: At least the last 2 sentences sound as if you emptied the lid!

Comment: *After* taking off the jar's lid, I emptied it. Subordinating conjunctions can help to smooth over this problem, but not eliminate it. It always sound wrong to me when this occurs in a compound predicate as in your examples.

Comment: *"The intended meaning is that I emptied the jar after taking off its lid."* - There is no need to even mention the lid unless it has some special significance. If you say "I emptied the jar" everybody will understand that you must have removed the lid first because that's how jars work.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

I took the lid off the jar and emptied it.

Or maybe just:
I took off the lid and emptied the jar. (I can't imagine a context where it wouldn't be clear that it was the jar lid).